# Throw error when read large file

Tags: c#, .net

I need to order according to the text of a line of text reading, when I read the file size of about 100MB, all is normal, but when I read the file and its size is about 300MB then the memory error occurs.

function detail as below:

```
var filePath = @"D:\junk\test.txt";
var fileSize = new FileInfo(filePath).Length;
var viewSize = fileSize
List<string> rowArray = new List<string>();
using (var mm = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, null, 0, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
using (var stream = mm.CreateViewStream(0, viewSize, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    rowArray.Add(reader.ReadLine());
}
```

The `rowArray` is provided to the `ListView` datasource, `ListView` uses a virtual mode

What I have tried:

I use the third party software to read the file, whether it is the size of 100MB or 300MB size, everything is normal

Comment: You add to `rowArray` the result of [`reader.ReadToEnd()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend(v=vs.110).aspx) which I assume returns the Memory exception?

Comment: yes,your assume is right。and can you tell me how to slove and keep my purpose not change

Comment: You have a list rowArray, but you are adding the entire file to one row.  Why?  You should read one line at a time and add each row to a separate string.

Comment: no,at beginning,the rowArray is empty,so,i read one line and one line from file to fill the rowArray

Comment: Then you should be using reader.ReadLine(), not reader.ReadToEnd().

Comment: I'm sorry, this is a writing error, it is ReadLine

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you intend to do with the data. Do you need to load the whole file? Can you get away with processing it in chunks?